# Period domain closure and mixed Hodge structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

The moduli space of Hodge structures is the *period domain*
$$D\ = \ \coprod_{V,\psi} \text{Hom}_{\mathbf{R}\text{ alg.gp.}}(\mathbf{C}^*,G_\mathbf{R})/G_\mathbf{Z}$$
where $G\subseteq \text{GL}(V)$ are the linear maps preserving a given (skew)symmetric form $\psi$ on vector space $V$. There is a foliation on $D$ and a horizontal map
$$X \ \longrightarrow \ D$$
is the same thing as a variation of Hodge structures on $X$.

There are two other similar objects:

1. The compactification $\overline{D}$ of $D$: when the period domain is a variety, this exists by a theorem of Nagata.
2. The period domain $D_M$ of mixed Hodge structures.

**Question A:** what is the relation between 1 and 2? What are they both for the component $\mathbf{H}^g/\text{Sp}(2g,\mathbf{Z})$ of $D$?

My guess is that $\overline{D}\subseteq D_M$ because of limiting mixed Hodge stuctures. If they are *not* the same, then

**Question B:** what is $\overline{D}_M$?

Comment: The period domain is not a moduli space for Hodge structures, in the sense that there is no universal variation of Hodge structure on $D$. Rather, there is a certain foliation on $D$ and *horizontal* maps $X\to D$ correspond to VHS on $X$. This is Griffiths transversality.

Comment: Also, the period domain is not a variety in general. In situations where Griffiths transversality is automatic (e.g. weight 1 HS), then indeed the period domain is a moduli space for such VHS and is a variety (a Shimura variety).

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Thank you, I've edited my question accordingly.